# How can I make "sanitize_title" affect only one taxonomy?

Tags: slug, import

Is it possible to use the code:

```php
remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10 );
```

Is it possible to use the code not for all entities on the site, but only for one custom taxonomy?
My task is to make the custom taxonomy "petstores" with "." in slugs, and posts, pages and categories have default slugs.
For example:
`site.com/petstores/cathouse.net`
`site.com/category/veterinary-clinic`
For all WordPress entities, I don't want to include "sanitize_title" on my site, because then they are imported incorrectly and need additional processing.

Comment: this isn't standard WP behaviour, have you raised this as a bug on WP All Import?3rd party plugin/theme support questions are offtopic here, this isn't a place to get help with plugins/products you downloaded. Note that `sanitize_title` isn't changing your slugs directly, any code you write would only apply to new posts you create not old ones, but you will still need WP All Import help that you cannot recieve or ask for here

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am corresponding with their support team regarding this issue. I just wanted to know if it's possible in WordPress to allow dots in slugs not for all content, but just for one custom taxonomy?

Comment: btw why do you need dots in the permalink? And is it a hard requirement that the slug specifically has the dot, or is it actually that you can visit the URL with the dot and it still works and the slug is just the solution you came up for that? E.g. would a solution that allowed a user to visit `example.com/my.post.here` and have it redirect to `my-post-here` work too? Is this so you can put a file extension on the end e.g. `.html`? If it's adding an extension there are other much easier solutions that sidestep these problems

Comment: Dots in the custom taxonomy url are needed for the beauty of the decor, they imitate the address of the organization's website in the catalog. For example: "site.com/petstores/cathouse.net". No, I wouldn't do a redirect solution, it's easier to write "cathouse-net" right away. If it were possible to include a dot for the "petstores" taxonomy in WordPress, and leave the default generation for the rest of the entities, it would be nice.

Comment: I see, you should update your question to mention that, leading with that information makes your question significantly easier to understand and answer than what you asked. Also it seems that WP already supports using `.` instead of `-` even if the slug has no dots, if I take one of my personal sites posts and swap the `-`'s with `.`'s the URL still works, even though there are no dots in the permalink/slugs

Comment: Thank you. Updated the question. In wordpress 6.1.1 without including the code, the slug with "." shows 404.